# How to grouby only on one column sum others and do nothing to the reste with pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a DataFrame with more columns but I'll give you a smaller example,
I need to group on only one key, to sum the selected columns, without losing the other columns I had before

```py
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'color': ['blue', 'blue', 'yellow', 'yellow'], 'count': [1,3,4,5],'count2': [2,1,4,2],'bip': [2,2,11,1],'fix': ['A','B','C','D']})
df

    color   count   count2  bip    fix
0   blue    1         2      2      A
1   blue    3         1      2      B
2   yellow  4         4      11     C
3   yellow  5         2      1      D
```

Now i need to groupby color sum only on columns like : count1 and count2 without losing bip and fix informations so i need to get this :

```
    color   count   count2  bip    fix
0   blue    4         3      2      A
1   blue    4         3      2      B
2   yellow  9         6      11     C
3   yellow  9         6      1      D
```

Thank you for you helping :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `pandas.DataFrame.update`:

```
df.update(df.groupby('color')[['count', 'count2']].transform(sum))
print(df)
```

Output:

```
   bip   color  count  count2 fix
0    2    blue      4       3   A
1    2    blue      4       3   B
2   11  yellow      9       6   C
3    1  yellow      9       6   D
```